# Convert an array of arrays into a string?

Tags: php

```
array(
  array('foo' => '11'),
  array('bar' => '22'),
);
```

Given the array above, without using a loop, is it possible to output the following string?

```
'11 22'
```

Comment: Check this out. http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: `echo "'{$arr[0]['foo']} {$arr[1]['bar']}'"`

Comment: What are the edge cases? Does the outer array always contain one sub-array, or can it contain multiple arrays? If multiple, how to handle sepration between both? And why do you want it without a loop?

Comment: `$string = '';
$counter = 0;
array_walk_recursive($dataArray, function ($value) use (&$string, &$counter) { $string .= ($counter ? ' ' : '') . $value; ++$counter; });
var_dump($string);`

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way of doing this with one short line of code. `Implode` seemed like it could work, but I couldn't see how. Maybe a loop is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner:

```
$subject = array(
    array('foo' => '11'),
    array('bar' => '22'),
    array('bar' => '33'),
);

echo implode(" ", array_map("implode", $subject ));
```

> 11 22 33

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you have a multi dimensional array. Your top-level array has two elements (which are also arrays) with the index of '0' and '1' respectively.

Your child array is an associative array so instead of having an index of 0, 1, 2 ...n you have an index of 'foo' and 'bar' respectively.

So if you want to display the number 11...

```
$array = array(
  array('foo' => '11'),
  array('bar' => '22'),
);

echo $array[0]['foo'];
```

To make it into a sentence you would concatenate your two array elements

```
$array = array(
      array('foo' => '11'),
      array('bar' => '22'),
    );

    echo $array[0]['foo'] . ' ' . $array[1]['bar'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) method

**Solution :**

```
<?php

$a = array(
  array('foo' => '11'),
  array('bar' => '22'),
);

function glue($carry, $item){
    $carry .= array_values($item)[0]." ";
    return $carry;
};

var_dump(trim(array_reduce($a, "glue", "")));
?>
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/S8L0e)